# Update Textbox text automatically when data is inserted in database through web service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, textbox

I have a webservice that inserts the data into a SQL server database through a webmethod and another webmethod that shows the data of the database. I have made a windows form application that shows the data of the from the webservice the coding is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Web_Reference.Service1 service = new Web_Reference.Service1();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = service.connectoToSql();
    }
```

I haven't coded for textbox yet but i want that when the clients insert the data using HTTP POST into the database, the textbox text must be filled with the updated data automatically the user should be set free from clicking the refresh button every now and then.

Is there any sort of solution to this problem?
Can anyone provide any idea for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Timer control to check for data presence periodically and update the textbox accordingly.

Comment: @Ali .NET can u commet me know some link that can help me code this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me, it was very simple though works the best: I added a Timer and started it on page load. I removed the datagridview and took DataTable and in the timer click event loaded all the data from web service response and filled every textbox by the required data.

Now What happens is When the clients insert the data through HTTP POST it get inserted in the table with the current datetime and the application shows the latest data every second. This is what I required. Complete!

I hope this post helps other user in future.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        timer1.Start();            
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Web_Reference.Service1 service = new Web_Reference.Service1();
        DataTable dt = service.GetData();

        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Current_Amount"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Current_Qty"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Rate"].ToString();            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several opportunities to your question.

1. With a timer that goes 'checker' all time intervals when a new
   record is inserted into a table.

   If yes -> update the table ex.(`dataGridView1.DataSource = service.connectoToSql()`;)
2. With a system of "push notification" using a web service (already
   better in my opinion)
3. web socket...etc

Here is a rough example with the method "Timer" I would say the easiest ... However, the example below works with microsoft sql server and application coded in C #. Impossible to do better with your little information .. :

```
public static int Main() 
{
       /* Adds the event and the event handler for the method that will 
          process the timer event to the timer. */
       myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

       // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
       myTimer.Interval = 5000;
       myTimer.Start();

}
//Function called every half second
private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //Update the dataBase every half second
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
        MytextBox.Text = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I added a picture for a best explaination:
[image]

Comment: can u commet me know some link that can help me code this solution?

Comment: i have edited my answer for you with a little sample . I hope this help you

Comment: buhnard, but how is this possible in C# application that gets the data from a web service, i load it in the datagridview and show it in the text box, now when the data is updated from any client it gets updated on main DB but the app is static so how will it show the latest data in real time?

Comment: But the whole trick is! This is the client application that must execute the timer and update the textbox field.

Comment: i added a picture on top for you ;-)

Comment: I solved my problem myself but Your Timer logic helped me, thanks for your support, I am posting an answer which worked for me.

Comment: ok I'm curious to see the answer ^ ^ It was a pleasure friend